# implement Unsubscribe link in newsletter, what is the internal functionality as i am using amazon SES to send emails

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, amazon-ses

my template or newsletter needs unsubscribe link

I'm sending bulk emails of news letters from Amazon SES API using php, is amazon has unsubscribe link feature to unsubscribe recepients when they clicked.

i'm using database to send emails to Amazon SES api. Is there any feature in amazon SES to unsubscribe feature to my newsletter to reduce junk mails.

If a user clicks unsubscribe link he should not recieve mails from amazon SES.

Is there any process in amazon SES?
Please let me know.

In advance, Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, Amazon SES does not have an unsubscribe link feature, because it does not keep track of your mailing list. Amazon SES is used only to send the emails. The recipients and content of the emails are completely up to you.

Since you are maintaining your database of recipients, you would need to implement your own unsubscribe link and behavior. That would all happen outside of Amazon SES.

Comment: That is what i'm asking, my question is does aws has this feature or not? just like giving a link to template to unsubscribe or shall i implement my own unsubscribe link. --thank you.

Comment: @JeremyLindblom, is this answer still relvant? No changes?

Comment: I think that feature may exist now, although I haven't yet used it.  See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/sending-email-subscription-management.html.